# Delete Method Not Deleting

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that holds three arrays: one for the person's last name, one for the points scored and one for the player number.Now, I got all the arrays and everything done but for some reason my process delete method won't remove the items from the arrays. I know I asked a question similar to this but I can't seem to figure out why it won't delete properly

Any Help would be appreciated please and thank you

```
static Int32[] ProcessDelete(Int32[] playerNumbers, ref Int32 playerCount, 
    String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints )
{
    Int32[] newArray = new Int32[playerNumbers.Length - 1]; 
    String[] newArray2 = new String[playerLastName.Length - 1]; 
    Int32[] newArray3 = new Int32[playerPoints.Length - 1];

    int index = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    int index3 = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int t = 0;

    while (index < playerNumbers.Length)
    {
        if (index != playerCount)
        {
            newArray[j] = playerNumbers[index];
            j++;
        }

        index++;
    }

    while (index2 < playerLastName.Length)
    {
        if (index2 != playerCount)
        {
            newArray2[k] = playerLastName[index2];
            k++;
        }

        index2++;
    }

    while (index3 < playerLastName.Length)
    {
        if (index3 != playerCount)
        {
            newArray3[t] = playerPoints[index3];
            t++;
        }

        index3++;
    }

    return newArray;          
}

static void DeletePlayer(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName, 
    Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
{
    int player; // Player number to delete
    int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array

    if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        player = 
            GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
        playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);

        if (playerindex != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}",
                playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastName[playerindex], 
                playerPoints[playerindex]);

            Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
            Console.WriteLine();
            ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, ref playerCount, playerLastName, 
                playerPoints);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
    }            
}
```

Comment: have u debugged your code

Comment: i don't see any delete operation performing on arrays

Comment: You should have heeded the advice offered in your other question, by encapsulating all three pieces of information in a single type, and then storing instances of that type in a collection that directly supports the add/remove types of operations you want (e.g. a `List<T>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ProcessDelete` method constructs new arrays `newArray`, `newArray2`, and `newArray3`. Of these, it returns only `newArray`, so  `newArray2` and `newArray3` are thrown away. When `DeletePlayer` calls `ProcessDelete`, it ignores the return value, so `newArray` is also thrown away, and all the work performed in the body of `ProcessDelete` is wasted.